# C++: Function can't access variable defined in main() function

Tags: c++

Why can't the print() function access the msg variable?

```
#include <iostream>
void print()
{
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string msg{"Hello"};
    print();
}
```

```
Error: 'msg' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Because you can't, in C++? Why do you expect it to be accessible, in this manner?

Comment: what language are you coming from?

Comment: @KPCT From Python, I just started learning C++ yesterday.

Comment: I don’t think you can do this in Python either...

Comment: You should understand the scope of variables, there is plenty of material explaining this like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: it will work if you have class variable then all functions defined in that class can access that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `msg` variable that you have declared in the `main` function is a local variable and can be accessed only within the `main` function.

You can either define a global variable so that you can access it from any function, or you can pass `msg` as a parameter to the `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ program always begins execution at the main () function.

In the main function therefore, we declare a variable named `msg`  of type string and use it as an argument to call the `print ()`  function. Immediately this happens, the code 'steps out' into the print function and the string variable is printed out to console.

```
void print(std::string some_msg){
std::cout <<some_msg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string msg{"Hello"};
    print(msg);
}
```

I hope this clarifies.